# Switch Mojarra to MyFaces in WildFly

Tags: jsf, wildfly, wildfly-8, myfaces, mojarra

Why Wildfly uses Mojarra instead of MyFaces? In *JSF-Comparison: MyFaces vs. Mojarra* one of the main conclusions is

> Apache MyFaces performs lifecycle runs a lot faster than Mojarra, no
>   matter which state saving mechanism is used. [https://i.stack.imgur.com/4zcVX.png][1]

The truth of the said that article is irrelevant to WildFly but I'm just curious is it difficult to switch jsf impl to MyFaces in WidFly?

Answer (score 2):

The original article that the you refer to was very valid at the time it was posted. In the mean time (and way before you created your question) from the same site, just 1.5 months later is the [follow up](http://blog.oio.de/2013/05/16/jsf-performance-mojarra-improves-dramatically-with-latest-release/)

So the truth of the article where this image comes from is **very** relevant.

The actual perfomance differences now are small and most overhead is in **your** code and that is where you can gain the most.

Steps/options for switching Mojarra for myfaces can be found all over the internet https://www.google.nl/search?q=using+myfaces+in+wildfly

One good article: https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/DesignOfWildFlyMulti-JSFFeature (summary would be to complex to add here, so just a link)

Comment: Thanks, also I fount there that more than a year later they rerun the test suite http://blog.oio.de/2014/07/07/resurfaced-performance-issue-mojarra-fixed-2-2-7/ and they found that `An initial test showed that we can confirm this (2-2-7) and this latest release performs well even with larger component trees.`

Comment: Hmmm I always wondered why there were so many upvotes (don't think this answer deserved it, rather that the effort put in the question was to little since my answer came from the same site). But what I certainly did not expect was a downvote... weird... is it because I did not include text from the links I referred to? Explanation of why that is is in the answer. If the downvoter reads this, please respond... No hard feelings...

Comment: @Kukeltje "The truth of the article where this image comes from is very relevant" - I also don't understand what the image has to do with the article credibility. Perhaps it was a different image when you posted the answer? In any case, my impression is that the article was considered to be credible, that an issue was filed, and that a fix for that issue was applied to a later release of Mojarra. So I think the downvotes came because the answer seems to cast doubt on the article credibility with no basis for doing so.

Comment: @JohnDonn: Ok, that was certainly not my intention (and maybe due to not being a native English speaker). I rephrased it to make that clear.

Comment: And now it is plus 7, minus 3... :-)

Comment: @JohnDonn. Albeit 6+ year ago & searching for information re migrating WildFly Mojarra to MyFaces. An excellent response. I have encountered Mr. Kukeltje's  sarcasm many times over the years ...